# Are the Arcmesh materials broken? If so, how do I fix this?

Tags: mesh, materials, node-editor

The materials for the Window Arcimesh (Using the Archimesh add-on) were all black.
I entered the Node Editor to check it out, and found this material organization.

I'm unfamiliar with what is trying to be accomplished here, as these nodes imported with the add-on. 
What are they trying to accomplish here? Is the node format outdated? What was trying to be accomplished?

And...
How would I go about restoring the previous settings? If I can't, how would I go about redefining these textures to look at least similar to what was intended?

(Apologies if these are too many questions; I'm looking to learn).

[image: Node Editor]

Comment: That is one mess of a node tree! Not only it has a redundant connection (marked in red), but shader closures (green) should not be connected as color (yellow). Then the output node and the one marked as diffuse BSDF are nodes from blender internal, not cycles. Whatever is happening there is not right.

Comment: I can confirm that also in 2.79rc2 windows are created with such node material setup... this should probably be reported as a bug

Comment: This is the perfect opportunity to delete those materials and create your own... I guess.

Comment: @m.ardito Thanks for checking, it should be.

Comment: @cegaton Yeah, I'll probably just do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. I recreated the material nodes in my own fashion in order to continue. However, the Archimesh add-on will need to be updated to truly resolve the glitch.